# How to automatically enter proxy information

Tags: python, proxy

I used Python webrowser and opened Chrome, I want it to automatically enter username and password as shown in the picture and press "Sign In" to automatically enter the proxy. But I can't find a way yet. Here is my code snippet:

```
import webbrowser

url1 = 'google.com'
chorme_path = r'F:\Multichorme\theendnear1998\GoogleChromePortable.exe'
webbrowser.register('chorme', None, webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser(chorme_path))
webbrowser.get('chorme').open_new_tab(url1)
```

Is there a way to make it autofill?

[This is the dialog that appears automatically every time I go online using a proxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcwDk.png)

- Using selenium will have to operate on a completely new Chrome profile. While opening the webbrowser already provides the information.
- But the paradox here is that if using the webbrowser, it will be more difficult to fill in the login proxy information.

Comment: Is that your actual username and password? (edited out, just in case) I hope not, but if it is you might want to change your password...

Comment: Thanks. My question may not be the same as any other question because I have searched on stackoverflow about this topic but haven't found the answer yet.

Comment: Then you need to [edit] your question and show why/how it differs from the many other controlling-a-browser questions here. Right now, it doesn't look any different and mostly likely the answer is - use selenium

Comment: But using selenium will pop up a whole new chorme profile (not logged in account). But I want to operate on chorme that already has information. I think that's the difference.

Comment: Ok. As I'm not such an expert on selenium I will reopen the question. But please add as much details as possible of your problem, and if you saw SO questions it is good to link them and explain why they didn't help you

Comment: Your question is not deleted. It is just closed. Again, saying *"I did a lot of research and didn't find the answer"* is not helpful. You need to ***show*** the research you've done and explain the exact problems you're facing. As I said, if you don't show the research - this just looks like a duplicate. But again, since I'm not an expert on selenium and might miss some key points here, I'll reopen and let other experts decide

Comment: I'm sorry, let me remove that part and fix it.

Comment: Can I post one more question with a related topic? I wrote it but couldn't post it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If you have more details to the problem, [edit] the question. If you have a completely new question, yes - post another. Note that there's a rate limit of 90 minutes so you might not be able to do it just yet

Comment: It's a new issue so I thought it would be better to make a new question, I think I'll wait 90 minutes to post again. Thank you StackOverFlow boss ^_^